# Error from Azure function: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I followed the official documentation to set up my requirements.txt file. My understanding was that the function should be able to use modules if they are in requirements.txt. Here is an example of what that file looks like, with all the modules and their versions written in this way:

```
azure-common==1.1.12
azure-keyvault==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-resource==1.2.2
azure-storage-blob==12.3.1
azure-mgmt-subscription==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-network==10.2.0
azure-functions==1.2.1
```

However, when I look at the function's logs, I can see that it keeps throwing the error, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.common'". This is the first module I try to import in `__init__.py`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, may I know how did you generate the "requirements.txt" file ? Type the modules list or generated it by command ? And could you please provide more details about how did you deploy your function from local to azure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the modules you use in your function are all old version(such as `azure-common==1.1.12`, `azure-keyvault==1.0.0`.....). So could you please install the modules with the latest version. You can search them on this [page](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) and for example if install the latest `azure-common` module, just run the command `pip install azure-common`(no need the version number) it will install the latest version of the module.

And then use the command below in your VS code to generate the "requirements.txt" automatically.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

[image]

Then deploy the function code from local to azure by the command:

```
func azure functionapp publish <function app name> --build remote
```

It will deploy the code to azure and install the modules according to the content in the "requirements.txt" which you generated just now.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks for the tip about how to auto-generate requirements.txt.